# Need documentation for GPUImageColorMatrixFilter. Where can I find documentation for what the matrix means?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I would like to implement a bandpass filter using GPUImageColorMatrixFilter. Basically, blue would equal floor(blue - (k*red)) and both red and green would just end up being zero. Where can I find documentation indicating what the columns and rows of the matrix mean?

Answer (score 5):

My intuition would suggest that the 4x4 matrix is following the standard RGBA order and judging by the examples (see for instance `GPUImageSepiaFilter`) it looks like I'm right.

For instance, this is the identity `GPUMatrix4x4`

```
  R G B A
| 1 0 0 0 |  red
| 0 1 0 0 |  green
| 0 0 1 0 |  blue
| 0 0 0 1 |  alpha
```

Let's name each coefficient

```
  R G B A
| a b c d |  red
| e f g h |  green
| i j k l |  blue
| m n o p |  alpha
```

Applying the matrix to a RGBA color will result in the following R'G'B'A' color where the components are computed as

```
R' = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A
G' = e*R + f*G + g*B + h*A
B' = i*R + j*G + k*B + l*A
A' = m*R + n*G + o*B + p*A
```

which is nothing but the following matrix multiplication

```
| a b c d |   |R|   |R'|
| e f g h | x |G| = |G'|  
| i j k l |   |B|   |B'|
| m n o p |   |A|   |A'|
```

Comment: So, can I think of the columns as the input and the rows as the output, or is it the other way around?

Comment: Perfect! (Rows are the "output.")

Comment: how to control the intensity of the color filter here?